# the value parameter is not being passed using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parameter-passing

```
<textarea name="inputField" id="inputField" tabindex="1" rows="2" cols="40"onblur="DoBlur(this);" onfocus="DoFocus(this);" ></textarea>
<input class="submitButton inact" name="submit" type="submit" value="update" disabled="disabled" />
<input name="status_id" type="hidden">
```

the javascript(jquery):

```
function insertParamIntoField(anchor, param, field) {
       var query = anchor.search.substring(1, anchor.search.length).split('&');

       for(var i = 0, kv; i < query.length; i++) {
          kv = query[i].split('=', 2);
          if (kv[0] == param) {
             field.value = kv[1];
             return;
          }
       }
    }


$(function () {
    $("a.reply").click(function (e) {
       console.log("clicked");
       insertParamIntoField(this,"status_id",$("#status_id"));
       insertParamIntoField(this, "replyto", $("#inputField")[0]);


     $("#inputField").focus()

$("#inputField").val($("#inputField").val() + ' ');


     e.preventDefault();
       return false; // prevent default action
    });
});
```

the status_id parameter is not being passed:

```
post.php?reply_to=@muna&status_id=345667
```

it always give a value of zero, when its meant to give 345667

Comment: have you tried debugging the javascript using a debugger like Firefox with Firebug, Opera or Chrome?

Comment: i have never used firebug before, what deos it do? sorry a bit of a newbie here

Comment: With Firebug you can 'debug' the code. Stop where you want, check what values are set etc.

Comment: firebug is not helping at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems, the first @Guffa mentioned, you need an ID for `$("#status_id")` to work, like this:

```
<input id="status_id" name="status_id" type="hidden">
```

The other is here:

```
insertParamIntoField(this,"status_id",$("#status_id"));
insertParamIntoField(this, "replyto", $("#inputField")[0]);
```

Notice you don't have a `[0]` there, so you're setting `.value` on the jQuery object, not the element itself.  Instead you need this:

```
insertParamIntoField(this,"status_id",$("#status_id")[0]);
insertParamIntoField(this, "replyto", $("#inputField")[0]);
```

---

Or change your method to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), like this:

```
field.val(kv[1]);
```

And strip off the `[0]` calls so they're just

```
insertParamIntoField(this,"status_id",$("#status_id"));
insertParamIntoField(this, "replyto", $("#inputField"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any `id` on the field, so when you try to set the value using `$('#status_id')` it won't put the value anywhere.

Add the id to the field:

```
<input name="status_id" id="status_id" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

add value to input

```
<input name="status_id" id="status_id" value="345667" type="hidden">
```